# Divi theme clashing with Yoast SEO

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, yoast

has anybody experienced the Divi theme builder clashing with Yoast SEO v.7.6?

This problem occurred right after updating the Yoast plugin. I need some help please guy, as Yoast support doesn't seem to respond

Answer (score 0):

Yoast is at version 9.0.1 right now. I use Yoast with Divi just fine Yoast 7.6 is quite old. Maybe update and see what happens. Mine works fine

Answer (score 0):

Try the RankMatch plugin, it's suggested by Divi Support Team members.